# Difficult to replicate objects (object Customer) on the list?

Tags: c#

I wrote a program that does work with files like delete and update, store, and search And all customers But I have a problem with the method is LoadAll Once the data are read from the file and then Deserialize the object becomes But when I want to save the list of objects in the list are repeated. How can I prevent the duplication in this code?

```
var customerStr = File.ReadAllLines (address);
```

The code is written in `CustomerDataAccess` class `DataAccess Layer`.

[**Project File**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy6rp1rghyqjrs8/CoustomersApp.rar)

The main problem with the method `LoadAll` Code:

```
public ICollection<Customer> LoadAll()
{
    var alldata = File.ReadAllLines(address);

    List<Customer> lst = new List<Customer>();

    foreach (var s in alldata)
    {
        var objCustomer = customerSerializer.Deserialize(s);
        lst.Add(objCustomer);
    }

    return lst;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Customer> newList= lst.Distinct().ToList<Customer>();
```

Comment: Please expand more about the `IEqualityComparer` or `IEquatable`, or override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` for the distinct logic. Normally I don't think the `Distinct` here will result in non-duplicated objects since they may has different hash code.